# MvcForm calls Action for a partial view but is displaying as plain text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm following the video on Microsoft's Virtual Academy named "Developing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Applications Jump Start". In part 5: Integrating Javascript and MVC 4 they start showing off how to use PartialViewResults. I've copied the code exactly as they have in the video, however, I'm getting a different result. They don't show some of the code (SessionController) and it was required for me to figure that part out myself, so maybe that's where I'm messing up.

The problem is that my partial view being called by Html.Action is showing up as plain text instead of the HTML. Like below
[image]

I've tried Html.Action, Html.RenderAction, Html.Partial and Html.RenderPartial and all seem to give the same results. Any clue what I might be doing wrong here? I don't want to flood this post with a massive list of code, so I'll post code as requested, if necessary.

**EDIT: Requested Razor Code***

Step1:

```
@model MVC_Tutorial2.Models.Session
<h3>
    @Model.Title
</h3>
<div>
    @Model.Abstract
</div>
@Html.Action("_GetForSession", "Comment", new { sessionID = Model.SessionID })
```

Step2:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC_Tutorial2.Models.Comment>
<div id="comments>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var comment in Model) { 
            <li>@comment.Content</li>
    }
    </ul>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_Submit", "Comment", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "comments" })) { 
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Action("_CommentForm", new { SessionID = ViewBag.SessionID })
    }
</div>
```

Step3:

```
@model MVC_Tutorial2.Models.Comment
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SessionID)
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Content)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Content)
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
```

Comment: Can you show your razor and not just the ouput?

Comment: I updated it with my Razor code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get this exact behaviour if you haven't correctly linked in the required scripts.  Try adding the following at the top of your main view (not the partial):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Obviously make sure to include the correct version of jQuery you have available in your project.

### Update

As you already have the scripts there, something else is obviously wrong.  First thing I notice is this:

```
<div id="comments>
```

Note the missing quotation-mark.  As you have `UpdateTargetId = "comments"`, this may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: His issue is in the server side, not the client side code.

Comment: @DennisRongo His issue is he's trying to call a partial view using `Ajax.BeginForm()`.  Without the necessary scripts involved, it will return the view as a string.

Comment: These scripts already are linked (the non-min versions) on the page through the default App_Start BundleConfig.cs. I can see them in the final HTML of my page with the error.

Comment: @aladd04 Added a possible solution.

Comment: Hahahahhahahaa. Wow. Are you serious?! I spent 2 hours on a missing quotation mark!! :P. Thank you! That worked!